# Form Field Toggle

Tags: jquery

I'm building a form, and I need to specifically switch out two form fields depending on the country that is selected. One a select dropdown for US States and an input field for Province. They are built side by side, and when ever at any point the country is changed to lets say Africa, the input field becomes visible. And when the country United States is selected the States select drop down appears. Below is a simple example of the HTML.

```
<ul>
 <li><label>Country</label><select name="country"></li>
 <li><label>State/Province</label><select name="state"><input name="state"></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my jquery so far.

```
$("#billing_info select[name='state']").css('display', 'none');
$("#billing_info input[name='state']").css('display', 'none');
$("#billing_info select[name='country_code']").change(function () {
    if ($("select[name='country_code']") == "USA") {
        $("select[name='state']").css('display', 'visible');
        $("input[name='state']").prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        $("input[name='state']").css('display', 'visible');
        $("select[name='state']").prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

I'm having trouble getting this to actually work. What do I need to add to get this function to work properly, and to accept live changes will the page has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `display : visible`, change

```
$("select[name='state']").css('display', 'visible');
```

to

```
$("select[name='state']").show()
```

or use `display: block` or any of the other valid display properties, and you realize you're always disabling the `select` with the name `state` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `show()` and `hide()` to toggle the visible elements, like this...

```
// initially hide both elements
$("#billing_info select[name='state']").hide();
$("#billing_info input[name='state']").hide();

// toggle the visibility of the elements when a country is selected
$("#billing_info select[name='country_code']").change(function () {
    if ($("select[name='country_code']") == "USA") {
        $("select[name='state']").show();
        $("input[name='state']").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("input[name='state']").show();
        $("select[name='state']").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: That problem now is that when I want to go back to the United States, if this could be like a human error, the select State field doesn't show. The input field is still there.

Comment: The code I supplied *will* toggle the state select and input correctly.  There must be something else causing the issue.  If you can recreate the issue in jsFiddle then we can fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go... http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/zNZKa/

## HTML

```
<ul>
 <li>
     <label>Country</label>
     <select id="country">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
 </li>
 <li id="billing_info" style="display:none;"><label>State/Province</label><select name="state"><input name="state"></li>
</ul>
```

## CSS

```
li {list-style:none;display:inline;}
```

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#country').change(function() {
        $('#billing_info').show();
    });
});
```